# Creating a function that makes a list of integers

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function that takes in a sentinel value (an integer), and returns a list of integers. The function prompts the user to create a list of integers, using the provided sentinel value as the number the user enters to
exit the creation of the list. For answers please make it as simple as possible refrain from using any technique that is too advanced as I am still learning Python and do not want to jump too far ahead...

```
def createIntList():
    createlist = []
    while myInt != addNum: #having problems around here!!
        myInt = input("What do you want the sentinel to be?")
        addNum = input("Please enter a number, ", myInt, "to stop: ")
    createlist.append(addNum)
    return createlist
```

Comment: What version of Python ? Also you are trying to compare variables before creating them....

Comment: Where is `addNum` defined?

Comment: Where is `myInt` defined?

Comment: You want to ask the user each question once, so put that before `while`. You want to `append` many times, so put that within the `while` block.

Comment: `myInt` and `addNum` are defined in your `while` loop but used as stopping criteria in your `while` loop, you need to define them first

Comment: Also, if this is python 3, do `number = int(input('question'))`. If it is python 2, do `number = int(raw_input('question'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is really what `iter` is for , which can take as its first argument a function that takes no arguments and returns a value, and for its second argument a sentinal value that tells it when to stop

```
def get_int(prompt="Enter a number:"): 
    return input(prompt)

sentinal = input("Enter your sentinal:")
print( list(iter(get_int,sentinal)) )
```

alternatively you could write a method to accept the data until your sentinal is reached...

```
def input_until(prompt,sentinal):
   a = []
   while True:
       tmp = input(prompt)
       if tmp == sentinal: return a
       a.append(tmp)
```

the smallest change you could make to your existing code is

```
def createIntList():
    createlist = []
    #define both variables before your loop
    myInt = input("What do you want the sentinel to be?")
    addNum = None
    while myInt != addNum: #having problems around here!!
        #dont ask each time for a new sentinal...
        addNum = input("Please enter a number, "+ str(myInt)+ " to stop: ")
        createlist.append(addNum) # append your values inside the list...
    return createlist
```

Comment: When I try to run this via invoking it through a def main. I get an error,

def main(): 
    createIntList()
main()


I get an error like this
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hw6.py", line 37, in <module>
    main()
  File "hw6.py", line 35, in main
    createIntList()
  File "hw6.py", line 22, in createIntList
    addNum = input("Please enter a number, ", myInt, "to stop: ")
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3

Comment: thats cause you called input wrong... input is not like print where you just join strings with a comma... see  my edit I changed your code to fix that error also .... this class may be really hard for you you should refer to the python documentation on `input`